# Supported Java bit version on RaspberryPi Linux 3.18.7-v7+ arm

Tags: java, arm, raspberry-pi

It seems like linux ARM architecture supports only 32 bit java.

my OS architecture is [Linux 3.18.7-v7+ arm] and it is a raspberry pi.

I have tried installing both 64 bit and 32 bit java from below link.
Java 32 bit works but java 64 does not.

32 Bit:
http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u77-b03/jdk-8u77-linux-arm32-vfp-hflt.tar.gz

64 Bit:
http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u77-b03/jdk-8u77-linux-arm64-vfp-hflt.tar.gz

after installing 32 bit java if "java -version" command is executed it successfully returns version. like Java version : 1.8.0_77. But after installing 64 bit java if "java -version" command is executed it shows error : "unable to read binary file"

Is it really correct that only 32 bit java is supported for arm architecture

Comment: Are you running a 64-bit OS on your rpi3? If not, don't expect 64-bit software to work.

Comment: Actually it is RaspberryPi-2 and not RaspberryPi-3

Comment: Ok, even less reason for 64-bit software to work then. The rpi3 has a 64-bit CPU, but no 64-bit OS yet (AFAIK). The rpi2 on the other hand had a 32-bit CPU.

Comment: Thanks Michael for clearing doubt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Till RaspberryPi-2 until OS is 32-bit, so a 32-bit OS can not install the 64-bit java.